# What is LaTeX class for this book?

Tags: templates, book-design

I decided to translate a book but I have hard time to design my own LaTeX template for the book *Quantum Mechanics by Leonard Susskind & Art Friedman* Below is showing one page: I wonder what kind of LaTeX book class the author uses?

[image: Here is the one page]

Comment: With the right options and packages, almost every class can look like this... Well it is not standard `scrbook`, that's for sure.

Comment: It doesn't look like original `book` LaTeX template. I wonder which font they use?

Comment: You might take a look at the [LaTeX-Fontcatalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/), to see which font this might be

Comment: Rebuilding this with `scrbook` or any other book-class shouldn't be that hard, though.

Comment: @Skillmon: `book` with `headings` pagestyle, `amsmath` and `geometry` settings for `a5paper` etc, perhaps? (At least I have the impression that the page format is rather small)

Comment: @Skillmon, I didn't know there is a kind of page on which I may check many fonts visually.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sounds good, but I'm not that good with the standard classes. And `a5paper` can be wrong (page sizes without the dvi/pdf can be hard to guess, imho).

Comment: @Skillmon: I am not good with that KOMA thingy... and `a5paper` was a guess only.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I guess it's just about what you're used to use (and what was available when you started using LaTeX). For me this is/was KOMA.

Comment: @Skillmon: It would help to know when the original book and by which publisher was printed, this would give some clue to possible publisher-based classes

Comment: @ChristianHupfer and perhaps about the paper-size.

Comment: This book was published by *BASIC BOOKS* ( a member of the Perseus Books Group). I looked at their page but they have no LaTeX template for their books.

Comment: do you knowif  it was made with tex at all?

Comment: Their previous book (*The Theoretical Minimum*) was typed in MS Word (it was terrible) and later they changed it to LaTeX. But this design looks good on eye.

Comment: Well, it could look better, imho :) And for a book I would use `twoside`.

Comment: The font looks like the standard Computer Modern or Latin Modern.

Comment: @Skillmon: Don't judge a book by its 'cover' (singing like Frank'n'Furter ;-))

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are not really on-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Only guesswork and a magical 8-ball can answer the question. I vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This recreates the looks of your image (not exactly obviously):

```
\documentclass[%
  numbers=endperiod% For the point after the number, in your image it is used in headmarks but not at the actual headings
  ,a5paper%
  ,fontsize=12pt%
  ,egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles%
]{scrbook}


\usepackage[markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\headmark}% don't use the star if the chapter-pages should be head-less
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}%both right and left chapters
\automark*[section]{}%if there is a section right head containing section

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\cleardoublepage
\noindent
Or even more explicitly, we can combine three terms into a single matrix:
\begin{equation}
  \sigma_n = \begin{pmatrix}
    n_z & (n_x - in_y)\\
    (n_x+in_y) & -n_z
  \end{pmatrix}.
  \label{eq:sigma}
\end{equation}
What is this good for? Not much, until we find the eigenvectors and
eigenvalues of $\sigma_n$. But once we do that, we will know the possible
outcomes of a measurement along the direction of $\hat{n}$. And we will also
be able to calculate probabilities for those outcomes. In other words, we will
have a complete picture of spin measurements in three-dimensional space. That
is pretty darn cool, if I say so myself.

\section{Reaping the Results}
We are now positioned to make some real calculations, something that should make
your inner physicist jump for joy. Let's look at the special case where
$\hat{n}$ lies in the $x$-$z$ plane, which is the plane of this page. Since
$\hat{n}$ is a unit vector, we can write
\begin{align*}
  n_z = \cos\,\theta\\
  n_x = \sin\,\theta\\
  n_y = 0,
\end{align*}
where $\theta$ is the angle between the $z$ axis and the $\hat{n}$ axis.
Plugging these values into Eq.~\ref{eq:sigma}, we can write
\begin{equation*}
  \sigma_n = \begin{pmatrix}
    \cos\,\theta & \sin\,\theta\\
    \sin\,\theta & -\cos\,\theta
  \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all comments! I have already typed a few pages  of the book with those motivation. I wonder how to remove *the dot" after the section number (1.1.). In the book's section, no dot trailing the section number.

Comment: @ofenerci well I know how to change this in KOMA. Just leave out `numbers=endperiod` in my code.

Comment: Now we have a Perseus Books' LaTeX template for their "theoretical minimum" series :)  Feature books are now easy to edit.